# How to call other sequence from proxy service in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to call dbreport sequence from my proxy, but now I am facing a problem. I write the sequence and also the vfs proxy. But I can't figure out how to call that sequence from my proxy. I tried this "clone" and it works, but It only work when the proxy only called 1 sequence. My proxy :

```
<proxy name="SDL4"
      transports="vfs"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <class name="insert.data.proxy.TestInsertData4"/>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="start" value="start"/>
        </log>
        <clone>
           <target sequence="cobaInsert"/>
        </clone>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">xxx</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">xxx</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">xxx</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

and my dbreport sequence

```
<sequence name="cobaUpdate">
  <dbreport>
     <connection>
        <pool>
           <password>postgres</password>
           <user>postgres</user>
           <url>jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxdb</url>
           <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        </pool>
     </connection>
     <statement>
        <sql>update status set status = ? where id = ?</sql>
        <parameter xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   expression="get-property('status')"
                   type="VARCHAR"/>
        <parameter xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                   expression="get-property('id')"
                   type="INTEGER"/>
     </statement>
  </dbreport>
```

Is it the right way to call dbreport sequence from vfs proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sequence mediator instead of clone mediator;

Eg:

```
<sequence key="cobaUpdate"/>
```